# Relacionamento has_and_belongs_to_many Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho um modelo de **Item** *has_and_belongs_to_many* :generos e um modelo **Genero** *has_and_belongs_to_many* :itens, com isso possuo também uma tabela de relacionamento generos_itens(id_item, genero_id).

Estou tentando criar um novo relacionamento entre item e genero na *view* dos itens(show/1), primeiro buscaria todos os generos e então com esses dados incluiria esse novo relacionamento, mas como não possuo um modelo para a tabela **generos_itens** e também não tenho o controller não sei como fazer para inserir esse registro, qual o melhor modo de proceder?

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito de fazer isso seria gerar um modelo (não apenas a tabela) para essa relação muitos-para-muitos.

Esse modelo conteria os id's das duas tabelas relacionadas. (Dica: crie também um índice único para essas duas colunas).

E então você poderia criar um controlador para este modelo para trabalhar.

---

Porém se você não quer fazer isto o jeito de criar relações é assim:

```
@Item.generos = @array_de_generos
```

Assim tu vai ter que buscar todos os gêneros para o formulário para o usuário adicionar/deletar os que ele quer, e via controlador tu vai fazer algo parecido com a linha de código acima para recriar as relações daquele modelo.

Neste caso não tem o método `save`, a linha cima recria as relações.

*[Veja a documentação](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)*.

*[Veja também esta pergunta do StackOverflow-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240831/has-and-belongs-to-many-rails-4)*.